# SpringBoot update methods is working fine but doesn't update to entity on database

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

This is my service method.

```
    public UserDto updateUserS(Long id, UserDto userDto) {

    UserDto userDtoNew = null;

    if (userRepository.findById(id).isPresent()) {

        User existingUser = userRepository.findById(id).get();
        existingUser.setPassword(userDto.getPassword());
        existingUser.setUserName(userDto.getUserName());
        userDtoNew = userMapper.toDto(existingUser);

        return userDtoNew;
    }

    return userDtoNew;
}
```

And this is my controller method.

```
@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> updateUser(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody UserDto 
 userDto) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.updateUserS(id, userDto));

}
```

When I try to update my User by put request on a new json via Postman. My controller is working. I can see the new User on the Postman. But When I check my database  I saw the entity doesn't update in my database.

I didn't share all my codes like: entity, dto, repository, mapper. I'm using mapstruct as a mapper. Everythings is working fine.

I hope you can understand what am I missing.

Comment: Probably transaction management

Comment: Yes, It's working when I add the @Transactional annotation to my service class. I've been writing rest-apis for a few days but this is the first time it's happened to me. Can you guys explain why do I have to use this annotation?

Comment: Certainly because these annotation is handling the way your database related operations are treated by the framework. To simplify a lot, by default : without any COMMIT statment, nothing is persisted in your database. These annotation is using AOP to take care of the boilerplate code handling databases operations. Look at the `@Transactional` interface definition.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use @Transactional annotation.